Minimum energy to lift state of Utah one mile over 5-10 million years?
The following seems an elementary geophysics query, but I’m not sure
how to do a direct calculation.  My geology text mentions that over the
past 5 to 10 million years, the state of Utah and some adjacent states
were uplifted about one mile, by tectonic forces.  Part of this is the
Colorado Uplift and is responsible for the Grand Canyon.  So, I
wondered just what minimal amount of energy might be required to
do this work.  To keep it simple, I imagined just the area of Utah,
about 85,000 mi^2, converting it to sq meters: ~ 215 billion m^2.
I also imagine this entire ‘block’ of rock is, say, 10 kilometers, or
10,000 meters deep.  Again, for simplicity, I assume granite as a
fair proxy for all kinds of rock in question.  Granite weighs roughly
2,700 kg/m^3 .  This suggests a rough total mass of:
2,700 kg/m^3 x 215 10^9 m^2 x 10,000 m, or about 5.8 10^18 kg.
The uplift distance traveled is one mile or 1600 meters.  The Earth’s
gravitational acceleration “a” (=g) is about 9.8 m / s^2.  So….
I’ve made a crude attempt to estimate the minimal energy required
by assuming it may equal force x distance traveled.  ie:
Force x Distance = Mass * Acceleration * Distance, or
[5.810^18 kg]  x  [9.8 m/s^2]  x  [1600 m] = 9.1 X10^22 joules of energy.
(expended really over millions of years, by the way.)
But I don’t trust this estimate, since I suspect that there is a much
more elegant, accurate and direct solution available.
BTW, iff 9.110^22 joules were roughly correct, it would be the equivalent
of the energy coming from complete annihilation of about
1,011,000 kg of mass into energy.  That is, the approximate energy
of one million hydrogen bombs.  If true.
So is there a more accurate standard way of calculating the energy which
would be required?
Thanks,
Gene

It is not that the entire block was lifted. For those 5 to 10 million years erosion worked as well (that's why the Mesozoic sediments are currently exposed there). Also, Utah is not exactly granite, but more like sandstone. This will shave about one order of magnitude. However. try to estimate an energy necessary to create a Himalaya/Tibet/Pamir system.

Thanks for feedback.  And, yes, Utah is famous for beautifully eroded Mesozoic strata.  Though sandstone tends to be less dense, I doubt this would change the simplified calc. much.  And yes the Indian subcontinent colliding with Asia involves complexity and orders of magnitude more energy.  Nice challenge. --Gene--
